# Datapoints on top of complex barplots in R-software

Tags: r, bar-chart, vectorization

I have this fake data frame. I am looking at a quicker vectorization to add data points over the barplot of means. My solution would be hard to apply when many columns are present. My problem is that only a vector and not a matrix is allowed in the "points" functions. Do you have a smart solution?

```
df <- data.frame(Test = 1:5,
    Factor= c("A","A","B","B","A"),
    V1=c(3.2,5.4,6.0,6.5,2),
    V2=c(5,5,8.6,7,1))

str(df, list.len=ncol(df))
colnames(df)
dim(df)

df.agg <- aggregate(df[c(3,4)], by = list(Factor = df$Factor), mean)
df.agg <- df.agg[order(df.agg$Factor),]
df.agg

mat.agg <- as.matrix(df.agg[c(2,3)])

barx <- barplot(mat.agg, 
        beside = T,
        ylim = c(0, 1.3*max(mat.agg)),
        col = colors()[c(5,16)][df.agg$Factor],
        legend.text = as.character(df.agg$Factor))
barx
barx <- as.vector(barx)
barx

points(
  rep(barx[1], length(df[df$Factor == levels(df$Factor)[1], "V1"])),
  df[df$Factor == levels(df$Factor)[1], "V1"])

points(
  rep(barx[2], length(df[df$Factor == levels(df$Factor)[2], "V1"])),
  df[df$Factor == levels(df$Factor)[2], "V1"])

points(
  rep(barx[3], length(df[df$Factor == levels(df$Factor)[1], "V2"])),
  df[df$Factor == levels(df$Factor)[1], "V2"])

points(
  rep(barx[4], length(df[df$Factor == levels(df$Factor)[2], "V2"])),
  df[df$Factor == levels(df$Factor)[2], "V2"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Test, -Factor) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = key, y = value, fill=Factor)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean",position = "dodge") + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

In base R I would do:

```
library(reshape2)
df_wide <- melt(df[,-1]) # make your data wide
df_wide <- df_wide[ order(df_wide$variable,df_wide$Factor),] # order appropriate
# add the x-positions using interaction 
df_wide$X <- barx[as.numeric(interaction(df_wide$Factor, df_wide$variable))]
# add the points to the bars
points(df_wide$X, df_wide$value)
```

[image]

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please accept it.